# Allowing Items created on droppable event be draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I am working on a custom workflow style application. I am using jQuery UI for a drag and drop toolkit.

On dropping an item, I am rendering a bootstrap panel with various items in the body (depending on what was dropped).

Now, what I would like to do is allow these panels to be draggable again within the drop area, but I can't seem to achieve it.

Below is a link to the gist of the html. Ignore the linkme stuff, that's another aspect i'm working on. Ideally, the objects would be draggable anywhere within the solutions div.

https://gist.github.com/ajberry/0ab2c0adca4f92855b26b63f929b108d

I'm assuming it's something daft, and I have tried the following with no success:

```
$( ".panel-default" ).draggable();
```

As I thought this would allow each panel to be draggable. I'm guessing it's to do with my droppable event or something.

Regards

Comment: Did you inspect the element (e.g., .panel-default) you want to be draggable() to see if the draggable classes are added to it?

Comment: Indeed, it wasn't adding the class. The issue was that I needed to give the panel the draggable attributes on the drop event (as they weren't rendered on page load).

Comment: Can I post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I added in the draggable attribute on the drop event. As prior to that the objects didn't exist so couldn't apply it.

```
function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
  var rownum = $("#solution .panel-default").length;
  console.log(rownum);
  var draggable = ui.draggable;
  var mytype = draggable.attr('class');
  if (!(mytype.includes("panel-default"))){
    renderChildControls(draggable.attr('id'), rownum)
    }
   $('.panel-default').draggable();
```

}